# Why does a StackOverflowError occur only when function doesn't use sequence destructing?

Tags: clojure

The following code was run on the 4closure site for [problem 19](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/19#prob-title).

The function I was writing was supposed to return the last element in a sequence.

A java.lang.StackOverflowError occurred for this definition:

```
(fn my-last [lst]
  (if (rest lst)
    (my-last (rest lst))
    (first lst)))
```

But when I ran the following definition it worked fine:

```
(fn my-last [[x & xs]]
  (if xs
    (my-last xs)
    x))
```

The only difference in the two blocks above seems to be the <strike>destructive sequence binding</strike> *use of destructuring* in the parameter list.

- So how come the first definition throws an error?
- And are there any differences between the two functions that I am missing?

Edit: fixed typo in first function definition

Comment: What is `get-last`? Is it supposed to be `my-last`?

Comment: oops. I changed it to my-last when posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
(rest [1 2 3]) => (2 3)
(rest [3]) => ()
(next [3]) => nil
```

Using `rest` returns the empty sequence `()`, which evaluates to `true` in your test.  Using `next` returns `nil` when there are no more items. Since Clojure considers `nil` the same as `false`, this will make it work.

Since many people get tripped up on this point, I would prefer a more explicit test, such as this:

```
(if-not (empty? ...))
```

or similar.

---

Update:

Here is how I would write it. The testing stuff [is from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]))

(defn get-last
  [items]
  (when (empty? items)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "get-last: items must not be empty")))
  (let [others (rest items)]
    (if (empty? others)
      (first items)
      (get-last others))))

(dotest
  (throws? (get-last []))
  (is= 1 (get-last [1]))
  (is= 2 (get-last [1 2]))
  (is= 3 (get-last [1 2 3])))
```

Some people will insist that the above example is not "pure" enough, but I think explicit clarity beats out implicit behavior every time.

---

Update #2

When in doubt, ask the code what it is doing:

```
(defn my-last
  [[x & xs]]
  (t/spyx {:x x :xs xs})
  (if xs
    (t/spyx (my-last xs))
    (t/spyx x)))
(dotest
  (t/spyx (my-last [1 2 3])))
```

results with:

```
{:x x, :xs xs} => {:x 1, :xs (2 3)}
{:x x, :xs xs} => {:x 2, :xs (3)}
{:x x, :xs xs} => {:x 3, :xs nil}
x => 3
(my-last xs) => 3
(my-last xs) => 3
(my-last [1 2 3]) => 3
```

And there you have your answer.

Comment: Does that mean that the destructive sequence binding (i.e the second example from the question) gives xs a value of nil when there is only 1 element in the list passed to the function?

Comment: See update #2. Also, "destructive" -> "destructuring".

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR answer:**
The first version was creating an **infinite loop** because that `if` statement will never be false since `(rest [x])` and `(rest [])` return a truthy value

**Pro Tip: Here are some fun ways to break on an empty sequence**:

`empty?`

`seq`

`(zero? (count coll))`

The most idiomatic way is using `seq` with destructuring:

```
(fn my-last [[x & xs]]
 (if (seq xs)
   (my-last xs)
    x))
```

but you could have also wrapped your original solution in `seq` and it would have worked:

```
(fn my-last [lst]
  (if (seq (rest lst))
    (my-last (rest lst))
    (first lst)))
```

`(seq (rest lst))` will return `nil` which is a falsey value when lst only has one element which is what you were checking for.

A side note, another way you could have solved this is to

> ! get the first element of the reversed collection since for problem 19 only `last` is banned
>
> ! `(comp reverse first)`